# Como procurar numa coluna por valor =< 200 (executar comando)?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Pretendo procurar linha a linha dentro da coluna `P:P` um número inferior ou igual a 200 e executar um comando. Se for superior a 200 executar outro. Os valores estão definidos assim `0.0`.

```
If .Value =< 200 Then

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+30%)"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)

ElseIf .Value > 200 Then

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+40%)"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)

End If
```

RESPOSTA:

```
Sub teste()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("P1:P300") 'Se colocar P:P vai até à última linha

For Each Row In rng.Rows

If Row.Value < "200" Then

Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+30%)"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

ElseIf Row.Value >= "200" Then

Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+40%)"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

End for

End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Não estou a perceber como atribuir o .value à coluna @bfavaretto

Comment: Como é que faço para procurar linha a linha dentro da coluna e comparar os valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer um *loop* em uma coluna pode-se fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
Dim rng as Range

Set rng = Selection ' ou Range("A1:A30") ou Range("P:P") no seu caso...

For Each Row In rng.Rows

 ' Seu código aqui...
 ' If row.value >= 200 Then 
 ' [...]

Next Row
```

**Cuidado** com *loop* muito grande, em função do desempenho. Creio que seria melhor saber até qual linha possui dados, para que não precise rodar o *For Each* por todas as linhas do Excel.

Outra opção seria usar da seguinte maneira dentro do *For Each*, para verificar se existe algum valor na célula:

```
For Each Row In rng.Rows

 If Row.value = "" then

   Exit Sub ' ou _Function_ se for uma função

 End If
```

Ressalto que se tiver algum valor vazio entre os valores a função para neste ponto, devendo buscar outra forma de testar a célula para não usar recurso desnecessário.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário @Evert!

Comment: Não estou a conseguir executar o código, o Excel congela!

Comment: Como é que atribuo a leitura até à última linha em `set rng` @Evert?

Comment: Para atribuir a coluna toda use o exemplo 'range ("P:P")'. Vc está colocando o código dentre de 'Sub NOME ()' e 'End Sub'?

Comment: Então funcionou? Se sim marque como resposta válida. Sobre seu código, vi que atualizou sua pergunta... no seu código ele pega sempre a mesma célula "U2" para colocar sua fórmula... se for isso que quer de fato, creio que encontrou sua resposta. Se não for e ainda tiver algum ponto em aberto, sugiro postar nova questão e deixar esta para referência futura. Abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado @Evert!